# How to Create Dynamic table which row including two cutom check boxes in Android

Tags: android

i want to crate dynamic table which row contain two check boxes(custom check box) and i want to give  to that check box  onCheck or onClick event to that particular check box ..how to create such type of dynamic layout in Android??   Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        final TableRow table_row = new TableRow(this);

        final TextView tv_items = new TextView(this);


        tv_items.setText("Textbox"+i);

        final CheckBox chk_box_1 = new CheckBox(this);
        //final CheckBox chk_box_2 = new CheckBox(this);

        table_row.addView(tv_items);
        table_row.addView(chk_box_selected_food);

        table.addView(table_row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        chk_box_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){ 
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(chk_1.isChecked())
                {
                    //your code
                }
                else
                {
                    //your code             
                {

            }

        });

    }
```

The textview is just for demonstration purpose..you can have another checkbox and can handle the same as the first one